# how do i remove monitored hosts from graphite console

Tags: graphite

I was able to setup graphite,carbon and whisper without a problem. 
 I have collectd sending data into carbon and all of that is working great. 
 I can generate graphs look at reports without a problem. 
 Now a couple of the VM's that were being monitored have been removed.
How do i remove these VM's from the graphite console and purge their data from whisper? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graphite-webapp dynamically generates the graph-tree from the contents of the file-system at the location of the storage. The default is- `/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/stats/`. Delete the `.wsp` files and they will no longer appear in the webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the whisper files is the first step, but you also will need to cull the empty directories from your whisper directory:

```
find /var/lib/carbon/whisper -type d -empty | xargs sudo rmdir
```